# MarkLogic Alerting Error: No default permissions for document creation

Tags: permissions, real-time, alert, marklogic

### MarkLogic: Current user does not have default permissions for document creation.

> Prerequisite

I have downloaded the MarkLogic sample alerting repository from [this link](https://github.com/marklogic-community/alerting) and configured all settings to specification.

> Issue

When I try to `Create a New Content Post` with arbitrary data, as shown below, I get a permissions error.

### Content Post:

[image: MarkLogic Content Post]

### Permissions Error:

[image: Error]

> Relevant Information

I am new to MarkLogic, but I am sure I am using the service as an admin (check Permissions Error screenshot for clarification). There isn't much good documentation of the service for new users, so I was not able to find a solution that involved granting further permissions to `admin`.

**Thanks so much in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what application this is, but there it looks like you'll need to go in through the admin console and add default permissions to the admin role. The app is expecting there to be some, but by default there aren't any.

You can simply create default permissions to the role that give admin read, insert, and update.

The intended use would be to use roles/users other than admin...

To configure default permissions for a role using the administrative console, do the following:

1. Login to the admin console (usually the HTTP app on port 8001- http://localhost:8001)
2. In the navigation menu to the left, click on security, then roles, then click the target role (in this case, admin). By default, the configure tab is selected.
3. Scroll to the bottom of the page to the section titled, "default permissions" and create a set of default permissions by selecting a role/capability pair. In this case, use admin as the role and read, then click "more permissions" and select admin role with insert, and then repeat for admin/update.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've been trying to figure out the procedure to do this for a while already. Do you happen to have a step-by-step procedure to change default permissions?

Comment: Updated the answer to include the steps. Sorry I didn't see your comment sooner!

Comment: Thank you so much! The `more permissions` option is what I had completely overlooked. Also, sorry for the late response, I had this issue at work and just got back! Many thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped!